# How to run Jboss 4.2.1 on IP address?

Tags: java, jboss, jakarta-ee

I have a web application deployed on the Jboss 4.2.1 server. I can access the application using following URL.

http://localhost:8080/myApp

But I am not able to run the application using my machines IP address like below.

http://192.168.0.100:8080/myApp

I want other developers on my network to be able to test the application deployed on my machine using my IP address.

What are the changes that I need to do in the JBoss configuration so that I can access Jboss using the IP address instead of the localhost?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to an extra flag while running. ./run.sh -b0.0.0.0

Comment: I am using eclipse to start my jboss. Is it possible to configure this in eclipse?

Comment: Are the steps same if i need to do it on the Jboss web 1.0.1?

Comment: I have not used jboss web, but you can try it. I believe it should work.